# Trying to change attributes like Title and back button on navigationcontroler

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to set the back button on the navigation controller that currently has my view on the stack.
I can not change any of its attributes.

Is there an way I can grap the top most navigation controller like: [self navigationcontroller]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the back button in a `UINavigationController` is owned by the parent.

Simply set the back button before you call `pushViewController:`

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@"Go Back" 
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:nil 
                                       action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewController];
```

(taken from [this tutorial](http://astralbodies.net/blog/2011/03/20/ios-basics-uinavigation-controller-back-button-text/))

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this info!

Answer (score 1):

You can access your `NavigationController` with `self.navigationController`. Just as you would when pushing and popping `ViewControllers`.

By default, your `NavigationController` grabs the title from your `ViewController`, so you just have to set that like this;

```
self.title = @"My title";
```

And to access the back button;

```
self.navigationController.backBarButtonItem
```

[UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem)

Answer (score 0):

Setting title:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:tabTitle];
```

setting barButton appearance

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font-Name" size:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont, [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```